# Error when attempting to save Notebook. Cause and solution?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, warning-messages, windows, save

I am experiencing an error attempting to save a modified Notebook in *Mathematica* 10 under Windows.

The error I get is:

> ```
> Could not access the directory X:\Docs\\Mathematica. You should check that directory's permissions.
> ```

Note the doubled `\\`.  The correct path is `X:\Docs\Mathematica`.

`NotebookDirectory[]` returns the correct (escaped) path:

```
NotebookDirectory[]
```

> ```
> "X:\\Docs\\Mathematica\\"
> ```

***Correction***: This is happening with multiple (all?) Notebooks in this path in the current session.

Has anyone else experienced this error?  How can I determine its cause and seek a solution?

Answer (score 3):

For the aid of anyone else who runs into this issue I seem to have figured out the compounding factors necessary to recreate this problem.

1. Create a Windows directory `C:\foo\bar`
2. Save arbitrary Notebook `example.nb` to this directory
3. Using the Option Inspector add to `NotebookPath` exactly: `"C:\\foo\\bar"`
4. Close and restart *Mathematica*
5. Create a new Notebook and run `NotebookOpen["example.nb"]`
6. Modify the content of `example.nb` and attempt to save it

The fix for the problem seems to be as simple as changing the `NotebookPath` entry to:

```
"C:\foo\bar"
```

Why the problem occurs I don't know.  Clearly the escaped string `\\` form is accepted as the Notebook is found by `NotebookGet` but apparently it isn't recognized during the save process.  The problem also doesn't happen with a single level path such as `"C:\\foo"`.

Comment: "100k" pop up with me. Thanks for your rare combination of politeness and knowledge :)

Comment: @eldo Thank you.